# Why is there a need to repeat formula in the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am currently self-studying MIT's Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python. However, I am having trouble with the loop part. Like in this case, why is there a need to repeat the formula ans = (high+low)/2 again in the while loop?

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans)
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low)/2.0
print('numGuesses =', numGuesses)
print(ans, 'is close to square root of', x)
```

It is a similar thing for problem set 1b, where I need to repeat the formula for monthly_saved.

```
annual_salary=float(input("Enter your starting annual salary:"))
monthly_salary=annual_salary/12
portion_saved=float(input("Enter the portion of salary to be saved:"))
total_cost=float(input("Enter the cost of your dream home:"))
semi_annual_raise=float(input("Enter your semi annual salary raise:"))
portion_down_payment=0.25 * total_cost
monthly_saved=portion_saved * monthly_salary
current_savings=0.0
months=0
annual_return = 0.04
while current_savings <= portion_down_payment:
    monthly_return_investment=current_savings * (annual_return/12)
    monthly_saved=portion_saved * monthly_salary #why must I include this line to obtain the correct answer?       
    current_savings = current_savings + monthly_saved +  monthly_return_investment
    months += 1
    if months%6 == 0:
        monthly_salary += monthly_salary*(semi_annual_raise)
print("Number of months",months)
```

Comment: Please do not post code as image, it discouages attempts to run the code to examine it. Furthermore, links tend to get broken, making questions useless in the future

Comment: That's how the algorithm works, I guess? What's the problem here?

Comment: The formula is repeated because the (initialized) value is used in the `while` condition. Then it is again re-calculated in the loop.

Comment: Python does not have a "do while" loop that guarantees tha code inside the loop will be executed at least one time. That's why it has to be replaced with a "while" loop together with value initialization abobe the loop.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I think you have a conceptual problem here. `ans = (high+low)/2` doesn't define a formula for calculating `ans`. It simply performs that calculation of `ans` with the current values of `high` and `low`. If you need to calculate a new `ans` later with different `high` and `low`, then you need to repeat that statement, or get Python to repeat it for you by placing it in a loop. If you want to define a formula, you need to create a function.

Comment: I am sorry for posting the code as an image since this is my first time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are updating the `low` and `high` variables inside the loop, and you want an updated `ans` value using the new values for the two variables.

You can see the loop's condition includes `ans` so it makes sense to update `ans` until the while condition is no longer true.

Comment: Then what about the second block of code for problem set 1b, where I have to repeat the formula for `monthly_saved` ? In this case, is it also because the variable `monthly_salary` is being updated in the loop?

Comment: @TomTom that is correct. You can see that `monthly_saved` is being used to recalculate `current_savings`, which is one of the conditions for the loop. Once `current_savings` becomes higher than `portion_down_payment`, the loop condition becomes False and the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can have **do ... while** loop like this:

```
while True:
  do_staff()
  if fail_condition:
    break
```

or

```
do_staff()
while not fail_condition:
  do_staff()
```